Mimedata objects are being deleted
I have a short script designed to keep a list of clipboard items for easy access. I am using QMimeData objects referenced by a list. However, the script keeps crashing because Python seems to be deleting older objects.
Thanks,
I tried strengthening the reference with another list, but I am still experiencing the same issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
